# How to echo/print attribute set name on frontend catalog page

Tags: catalog, frontend, attribute-set

Magento CE 1.9.0.1

I'm interested in echoing out the product attribute set name on the catalog/category pages. This sounds like a strange thing to do but we use Magento's attribute set in a unique way for classifying products.

I was attempting to pull it from the *Mage::getModel('catalog/category')* feature in my page template but was unsuccessful.

I also tried to pull the name with the following code:

```
$attributeSetModel = Mage::getModel("eav/entity_attribute_set");
$attributeSetModel->load($product->getAttributeSetId());
$attributeSetName  = $attributeSetModel->getAttributeSetName();
echo "<p>" . $attributeSetName "</p>";
```

Is there a way to get the name to display with their products on the frontend catalog pages? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you mean u need to print attribute set nsme on the product list page (ie when u click on the category url) ?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add the following code in your catalog/product/list.phtml

```
<?php
$attributeSetModel = Mage::getModel("eav/entity_attribute_set");
$attributeSetModel->load($_product->getAttributeSetId()); // $product is your product object
echo $attributeSetName = $attributeSetModel->getAttributeSetName();
?>
```

Note check your listing of products is in grid mode or list mode and add accordingly above code

Please check for more in detail http://learnnewtechnologiesonline.com/magentoget-the-attribute-set-name-of-a-product-in-magento/

Comment: That's it! Worked perfectly. Last question: Do you know if it's possible to group products from the same attribute sets together (sort by ascending > attribute set name)?

Comment: will check and reply

Comment: Either way, thank you very much for your help Pradeep!

Comment: you need by attribute_set_id or attribute_set_name ?

Comment: Either would be acceptable.

Comment: i got product list collection by attribute_set_id

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53976/sort-products-in-frontend-based-on-which-attribute-set-they-belong-to

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20700/discussion-between-deeperdata-and-pradeep-sanku).